# Trying to list terms of a custom taxonomy using get_categories

Tags: taxonomy, categories

I'm using this little snippet of code to try and list the terms of a custom taxonomy for use in a meta box select box but it doesn't show anything when I implement it (Despite working with the default 'category' taxonomy)

```
$partners = array();
$partners_obj = get_categories(array('taxonomy' => 'partner-cat'));
$partners[''] = '-';
foreach ($partners_obj as $partner) {
    $partners[$partner->cat_ID] = $partner->cat_name;;
}
```

As you can see, my custom taxonomy is 'partner-cat' and there are posts in a custom post type in 2 separate terms of this taxonomy.

Any help would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

```
get_categories()
```

fetches taxonomies of type 'categories' particularly http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.6/wp-includes/category.php#L0,
 to fetch custom taxonomy you should use get_terms() instead, here http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_terms

```
$terms = get_terms( 'partner-cat', 'orderby=count&hide_empty=0' );
$count = count($terms);
if ( $count > 0 ){
 echo "<ul>";
 foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
   echo "<li>" . $term->name . "</li>";

 }
 echo "</ul>";
}
```

Make sure you specify the proper slug you registered for taxonomy and change WP_DEBUG to true in your config file to check for further errors, as you might be fetching the taxonomy before you are registering it and hence no results in that case you'd get an error.

can you paste your code for registering taxonomy?

Comment: I didn't even think of that! I was including the meta box function BEFORE my custom taxonomy function. I switched them around and it works perfectly now. Thank you!

Comment: ok great... :), easy solution, so you should mark it as answer I guess :P

Answer (score 1):

Are your taxonomy terms empty? They will not show by default. You could try using:

```
$partners_obj = get_terms( 'partner-cat', array('hide_empty' => false) );
```

Note that `get_categories()` uses `get_term()` to fetch your terms.

Your `foreach` isn't good too. you should access `term_id` and `name` instead.

```
foreach ($partners_obj as $partner) {
    $partners[$partner->term_id] = $partner->name;
}
```

Whole code:

```
$partners = array();

$partners_obj =  get_terms( 'taxo-name-here', array('hide_empty' => false) );
echo '<pre>' . print_r( $partners_obj, true ) . '</pre>';
echo '<hr>';
$partners[''] = '-';
foreach ($partners_obj as $partner) {
    $partners[$partner->term_id] = $partner->name;;
}

echo '<pre>' . print_r( $partners, true ) . '</pre>';
```

Comment: No, they both have posts in them. `get_terms( 'partner-cat', array('hide_empty' => false) );` didn't work either... It's odd because it works fine with the default post categories

Comment: Updated answer. it works for me.

Comment: I gave that a try and still no luck, although it did throw up an error telling me the taxonomy was invalid.... I've double and triple checked the name and it's correct so I don't know why it's doing that

Comment: `get_terms` return `wP_Error` when the taxonomy does not exist. Could you try with another taxonomy? how are you creating this one? codes or plugin?

Comment: I've just tried it with another custom taxonomy, same error. Then I tried it with the default "category" one and it worked. Both custom taxonomies do exist though and both have posts... I'm coding it in myself, no plugin

Comment: can you show the code you used for the taxonomy? Add it to your question

Comment: Fixed it. It was a simple fix in the end, @dot1 led me to check which function I was fetching first and all I had to do was put my custom taxonomy function first and it's all working as it should now. Thanks for your help

Comment: Aren't you hooking your functions? Glad it worked :)

Answer (score 0):

if you are using Custom Post Types CPT and I assume you've created custom taxonomy for that custom post type lets say:

You have CPType named Products and you have CPTaxonomy named Products Categories

If you are trying to display the CPTaxonomy into your products page somewhere in the loop you I would suggest to use this function according WP codex:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_terms

the code to get the CPTaxonomy for the CPType both named products should be the following:

```
$categories = get_terms( 'products', 'orderby=count&hide_empty=0' );
```

then for displaying the taxonomies use this code:

```
<?php foreach($categories as $category):
 print $category->slug;print $category->name; 
?>
```

Comment: Just a tip, rather use variables like `$terms` and `$term` when working with term related functions like `get_terms`. It is less confusing than using a variable like `$categories` :-)

Comment: @PieterGoosen I know :), that's why I changed my variables from $terms to $categories :)

Answer (score 0):

**The Wordpress way:**

```
$categories = (array) get_terms('partner-cat', array('hide_empty' => false));
foreach (array_keys($categories) as $k)
{
    _make_cat_compat($categories[$k]);
}
```

This is using the direct implementation that Wordpress uses in function **get_categories()** located within *wp_includes\category.php*

Answer (score 0):

```
            <?php
                $args = array(
                    'type' =>'',//optional
                    'number' => '',
                    'hide_empty' => 0,
                    'taxonomy'  => 'product_cat' //your custom taxonomy name
                ); 
                $categories = get_categories($args); 
                //echo "<pre>";   print_r($categories);
                foreach($categories as $cat){
                    $catid = $cat->term_id;                 
                    $thumbnail_id = get_woocommerce_term_meta($catid, 'thumbnail_id', true );
                    $image = wp_get_attachment_url( $thumbnail_id );
                    $catname = $cat->name;
                    $catpage = $cat->slug;
                ?>
```

Comment: While sharing the source code to answer the question is helpful, it's also helpful to give an explanation. May you please answer how this code helps?